# nest if./else if statement default to last else even if parameters above are true

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```
Pizza.prototype.getPrice = function() {
  const price = 10
  if (this.pizzaSize === "medium") {
    if (this.toppings === "cheese") {
      console.log(price + 6);
    } else if (this.toppings === ("cheese", "pepperoni")) {
      console.log(price + 7);
    } else {
      console.log(price + 8);
    }
  } else if (this.pizzaSize === "large")  {
    if (this.toppings === "cheese") {
      console.log(price + 11);
    } else if (this.toppings === ("cheese", "pepperoni")) {
      console.log(price + 12);
    } else {
      console.log(price + 13);
    }
  } else if (this.pizzaSize === "xlarge") {
    if (this.toppings === "cheese") {
      console.log(price + 15);
    } else if (this.toppings === ("cheese", "pepperoni")) {
      console.log(price + 16);
    } else {
      console.log(price + 17);
    }
  }
}

function Pizza(pizzaSize, toppings) {
  this.pizzaSize = pizzaSize;
  this.toppings = toppings;
}

//UI Logic ---
function displayPizzaInfo(pizzaToDisplay) {
  let pizzaInfo = $("p#output");
  let htmlForPizzaInfo = pizzaToDisplay.pizzaSize + " " + pizzaToDisplay.toppings + " Pizza" + " " + "$ " + pizzaToDisplay.getPrice();
  pizzaInfo.html(htmlForPizzaInfo);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("form#pizzaOrder").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const pizzaSize = $("#pizzaSize").val();
    let ele = [];
    $("input:checkbox[name=topping]:checked").each(function() {
      ele.push($(this).val());
    })
    let myPizza = new Pizza(pizzaSize, ele)
    displayPizzaInfo(myPizza);
    // let myPizzaPrice = myPizza.getPrice();
    });
}); 

let myPizza = new Pizza("medium", "cheese");
myPizza.getPrice();
Expected Output: 
16
```

The test above no longer applies and the expected output becomes 18. I do believe either the way I'm writing my nested ifs or the if's are structured incorrectly. I did TDD and as I wrote my tests out they all worked not realizing my previous tests were no longer working. I'm looking to get my prototype.getPrice to match my if statements and therefore correspond correctly with what the user sees on the web application. Any help would be greatly appreciate. Thank you!

Comment: `("cheese", "pepperoni")` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: `this.toppings === ("cheese", "pepperoni")` this is not correct syntax, use `Array.includes` instead for ex.. `["cheese", "pepperoni"].includes(this.toppings)`

Comment: so then it would be looking for a value of 2 then versus it looking into an array for those properties.

Comment: ```
Pizza.prototype.getPrice = function() {
  const price = 10
  if (this.pizzaSize === "medium") {
    if (["cheese"].includes(this.toppings)) {
      console.log(price + 6);
```
That just seems backward like it would be searching for this.toppings when this.toppings holds the array of ["cheese", "pepperoni"}

Comment: I was able to refractor with switch cases! thanks for all the insight